# Basic Javascript - Applying to style to two classes

Tags: javascript, jquery

Sorry for the really basic question.

I'm trying to apply two different classed to to two different divs at the same point on scroll.

Currently the JS looks like this

```
if ( position > 480 && !(docViewBottom >= elemTop)) {
$('#work').css({'position':'fixed', 'top':'0', 'height':'100vh'});
} else {
```

but how do I add a addition div and style with something like

```
if ( position > 480 && !(docViewBottom >= elemTop)) {
$('#work').css({'position':'fixed', 'top':'0', 'height':'100vh'}
#workslider {'position: fixed'});
} else {
```

Comment: Does the div exist already, or do you want to create it and insert it (with styling) dynamically?

Comment: the div exists, just need to add the style

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To style the both elements with same style:

```
$('#work,#workslider').css({'position':'fixed', 'top':'0', 'height':'100vh'});
```

for just setting css position fixed for both:

```
$('#work,#workslider').css('position','fixed');
$('#work').css({'top':'0', 'height':'100vh'});
```

Comment: "different classed to to two different divs"

Comment: @Alex:was updating only

Comment: @Alex: glad it helps rob :)